# How to turn off animation preview in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

### Context

I am creating a PowerPoint presentation and I am adding a lot of animations. The animations are too fancy: I am using appear and disappear to draw attention to specific parts of image.

### Issue

When adding animations, PowerPoint will preview the animation as I add it (including adding additional animations). The appear and disappear are short, but the preview locks most UI controls.

I know what the animations look like and want to focus on adding, ordering, and timing.

### Question

> How do I turn off animation preview in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the **Animations** ribbon tab in the **Preview** group, Click the **Preview** drop-down and select **AutoPreview** (represented with a checkmark when enabled).

[image: Disabling animation auto preview in PowerPoint 2010]